# Formatting Django request cookies

Tags: python, json, django, cookies

Am trying to format the cookies result coming from the request in django.

```
def submitcheckout(request):
    print(request.COOKIES['cart'])
```

the result of the print command is

```
[{%22cartprice%22:%22333%22%2C%22cartimg%22:%22/media/CACHE/images/uploads/7-1_BLY84nL/ec71ea409aa7d89935e9a24ef6f7883e.jpg%22%2C%22cartname%22:%22Bat-hub%22%2C%22cartid%22:%227%22}]
```

Running this command also `print(type(request.COOKIES['cart']))`return a data type of `str` which shows its a string. the string is useless to me now becuase i don't know how to remove the padded %22 and the likes added to represent space. The Cookies was an array from the browser.

Have try using `json.dump` and `json.load` but none of the two worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use urllib to remove the characters described. See the code below.

```
import urllib
def submitcheckout(request):
    print(urllib.unquote(request.COOKIES['cart']))
```

Comment: No problem, if you have a different solution than mine, please update your question with your answer for others that might come across the same problem.

Comment: have accepted your answer, because its the first step, then you use `json.loads(result)` to convert it to json

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out
first use urllib to convert it to normal text, then convert load json object using `json.loads()` function

```
import urllib
import json
def submitcheckout(request):
    result = urllib.unquote(request.COOKIES['cart'])
    json_result = json.loads(result)
```